# Copy as Curl been blocked, but Replay no problem, how?

Tags: http, curl, webdriver, web-crawler, httpclient

In Browser Dev Tools, like chrome and edge, I tried `Copy as CURL`,

[image: Copied as Curl]

This API should return an JSON body, but some HTML with code405 returned, seems like been blocked by some firewall.

**BUT, if I put `http_proxy=\"http://127.0.0.1:8888\"` after curl, It worked.**

8888 is port of MITM proxy, Charles also works, so I don't know the difference.

I compare all the Headers, all the same; no cookie for this request at all.

any other difference?

[image: Only Copy curl, Response]

[image: With local proxy, Response]

In my Java Application, My httpclient alse not work, I want to know how the target server know I'm not in a browser, and how can I get my expected JSON.

Thanks.

Comment: a few curl-detectors have become very sophisticated, going as far as detecting minor differences in the TLS/SSL negotiations to differentiate curl from chrome/firefox (they do have slight differences in how they negotiate, and it is detectable) - i believe 1 of the providers going *that far* is CloudFlare.

Comment: iirc there has been some pull requests to the curl project to make libcurl more google-chrome-like in its tls negotiation, but the curl maintainers weren't interested, or something like that.. my memory on the topic is fuzzy